# Phpunit.xml.dist Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I am trying to follow this link http://welcometothebundle.com/symfony2-rest-api-the-best-2013-way/. When I run this command :

> bin/phpunit -c app

I have this error :

> Configuration read from /home/ismail/NetBeansProjects/tuto/blog-rest-
>   symfony2/app/phpunit.xml.dist
>   **E.**
>   Time: 1.87 seconds, Memory: 15.75Mb
>
> **FAILURES!
>   `enter code here`Tests: 2, Assertions: 3, Errors: 1.**

ideas please ?!!

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that one of your `Tests` returned an error. Usually `PHPUnit` adds a `.` for every passed test, an `F` for assertion failure and an `E` for an error (e.g. an exception). Check your test code and correct it.